# C open/close pattern with possible error

Tags: c, resources

When we make an open/close mechanism for a resource that uses subresources, we have 2 patterns to handle the subresources release in case of error:

**1**

```
RESULT Open() {
   RESULT result;
   result = OpenSubResourceA();
   if (result == SUCCESS)
      result = OpenSubResourceB();

   /* Do not handle error case, the convention is that the caller 
    * will call Close whatever the return code of Open is */
   return result;
}
```

**2**

```
RESULT Open() {
   RESULT result;
   result = OpenSubResourceA();
   if (result == SUCCESS)
      result = OpenSubResourceB();

   if (result != SUCCESS)
      ReleaseSubResourceA();

   /* Release A if opening B failed since the convention is 
    * that the caller calls Close only if Open succeeds */

   return result;
}
```

Of course we can generalize with more than 2 subresources.

What's your favorite way of doing things ? And why ?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your inputs. The idea that the main resource shouldn't be in some intermediate state outside of the Open/Close calls convinced me that #2 is indeed the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If operation fails, the resource should be in the same state as before the call, so the client can continue using it. It is bad practice to leave resource in indeterminate half-ready state, if some operation has failed. If you can not (do not want to) cleanup and recover from indeterminate state, then resource should be explicitly rendered into error state, e.g. some member like `isError()` should start returning `true`

That is #2

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those things, that can't be done cleanly in C.

What I do is this pattern (very common):

```
   aquire_1;
   if (fail) goto fail_1;

   aquire_2;
   if (fail) goto fail_2;

fail_2:
    release_1;
fail_1:
    return err;
```

Comment: I like that, although my company's coding style forbids the use of goto, it doesn't kill readability here...

Comment: @Julien Yeah, it's probably the only valid use of `goto` :-D

Answer (score 1):

As a rule if I have a function that allocates resources - memory or file handles or anything - if the open method failed there should be no unallocated resources. A failed open should return the program back to the same state as it was if the open call had not happened at at.

So, I'd close unused resources in the open function. I think it is better to release resources as close to where you allocated them when possible. It makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what others have said, the caller to Open() might not even know of the existence of the sub-resources (depending upon the nature of the resource).  In that case the caller is quite unable to tidy up cleanly and the Open function must do it itself.

Comment: Well, the behaviour must of course be documented, so in case #1, the caller must *always* call close (which may lead to an easier design).